# Anaconda - Spyder is very slow to start on Windows 8 (checking for updates?)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

On my windows 8.1 laptop, the startup time for Spyder is:

1min 50 sec.... when I am connected to the internet
<25 sec .... when disconnected

I have already unchecked **check updates at startup** in advanced settings. Either that setting is ignored or perhaps there is another config file to edit?

Any ideas?

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 9):

I have a solution which works at least for now.

Just run `spyder --reset` from a terminal. **Warning**: you have to change the any interface settings all over again. But the startup time is now ~20 sec irrespective of an internet connection or whether **check updates** was selected.

(from)
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/MwJrkinW2To

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Still, 20 sec to boot is simply unacceptable for a glorified text editor.

Comment: Completely agree. Apparently no one closes their editor these days, so it doesn't matter.